# Get tr count using jQuery after removing certain rows

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get the count of tr in a table. I am using .remove() method to remove rows and after removing i want to get the count of remaining tr in the table. For this i am using .length in jQuery. But using .length i am getting wrong value.

```
     var rowCount = $('#tblid tr').length;
```

Comment: Can you show HTML markup?

Comment: `.length` should work, you maybe having problems elsewhere...

Comment: Works fine in a markup like this http://jsfiddle.net/775Gr/1/

Comment: Are you using `tr` elements in the `thead` or `tfoot` of the table? or just the `tbody`?